# the import org.eclipse(.emf) cant' be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf

I try to test the EMF API and work with EPackage, EClass,...

To do this I need to import org.eclipse.emf.Ecore if I am not mistaken.

The problem is that I get this org.eclipse cant' be resolved problem.
Itried many solution including installing EMFplugging, plugin devellopement environment, downloading and adding org.eclipse.emf jars to my build path (downloaded at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseemf260v201201231045jar.htm)

Do you know any tip to have an easy and quick solution (maybe an eclipse release or the correct jar file)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a package with (or install) EMF like https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-06/r/eclipse-modeling-tools and make sure to create "plug-in" projects where in the MANIFEST, tab 'dependencies' you have the plug-in containing e.g. org.eclipse.emf.ecore in there.